# Android: Can an EditText Within a ListView be Focused as Well as the List Item?

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext

I know that when you allow focus to any "focusable" object within a ListView it disables the ability to focus on the ListView itself. I have an EditText and a couple buttons inside my ListView item, but I also want to be able to use a ContextMenu with the ListView so I need to be able to maintain focus. Is there a way to override so that both my ListView and EditText box can receive focus? I assume if it is possible it would be done within the custom adapter. I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter and managing my button clicks within the NewView method. My code is below:

```
public class GrainListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Button upButton;

public GrainListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainName);
    name.setText(getName);

    int originColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("origin");
    String getOrigin = cursor.getString(originColumn);
    TextView origin = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainOrigin);
    origin.setText(getOrigin);

    int lbsColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("lbs");
    String getLbs = cursor.getString(lbsColumn);
    EditText lbs = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainLbs);
    lbs.setText(getLbs);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grain_list_item, null);
    upButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.UpLbsButton);
    upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Grain Adapter Action", "Button CLICKED!!!");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: the problem is the layout. i hope you do have some space in the row for focussing. you can try onTouch or on Click for the view but i doubt it would be hardly of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
The video is long but great info on listview. At one point they explain it would confuse the application to know on which item you were selecting. I would consider adding another button or setting up a longclicklistener() and sharing it across all items in the listview.